# Should I use 'the' before the word 'banking system'?

Tags: articles, definite-articles

Should I use 'the' before the word 'banking system' when I refer banking system as a whole?

Comment: Depends upon the context. Are you referring to a particular banking system or banking system in general? If it's the former, you'd better keep it; otherwise no.

Comment: in general. So I can get rid of 'the', right?

Answer (score 0):

You technically can do either, but you will need to refer “to”. Otherwise it’s an awkward phrase. If you add a modifier, then there is more than one system. If you do not add the, you’re saying it’s one and only one system and there’s no lack of clarity as to what you mean.